# Word problem (creating a formula from data)

Tags: logarithms, word-problem

This question has been annoying me for a while now, I spent a lot of time trying to understand how to  turn this into a log based formula:

The light sensitivity of photographic films can be expressed in either DIN or ASA.

21 DIN are equivalent to 100 ASA.

If the sensitivity is doubled in ASA, the value in DIN increases by 3.

Which of these formulas describes the relationship between sensitivity measured in ASA (A) and DIN (D) if we use the approximation $\log_{10}2≅0.3$?

The correct answer for this is  $D=1+10⋅\log_{10}A.$

Now, I am not sure how to express correctly the doubling of A, is it simply $2*100A = 24D$  and if so can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed towards that final answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you have small inconsistency. First $A$ and $D$ are defined as two units of measurement for film sensitivity, so "21 DIN are equivalent to 100 ASA" could be rewritten as $21\ D=100\ A$ (like equation $1\ [inch] =
0.0254\ [meters]$). Then in equation $D=1+10\ \log_{10}(A)$ $A$ and $D$ are clearly real variables - contradiction! I will stick to former convention, then correct relation between ASA and DIN would be
$$x\ A=(1+10\ \log_{10}(x))\ D$$
This is helpful to calculate DIN, when ASA value $x$ is given.
Now doubling ASA yields:
$$2x\ A=(1+10\ \log_{10}(2x))\ D$$
and we can apply logarithm identity $ \log_b(xy)=\log_b(x)+\log_b(y)$ to get
$$1+10\ \log_{10}(2x)=1+10\ \log_{10}(x)+10\ \log_{10}(2)$$
$$2x\ A=(1+10\ \log_{10}(x)+10\ \log_{10}(2))\ D$$
so doubling ASA at any value $x$ increases DIN by constant $10\ \log_{10}(2) \approx 3$.

Sidenote: equation can be reversed to obtain ASA from DIN:
$$ y\ D = 10^{\frac{y-1}{10}}\ A $$